# how it can be that a single user causes conflicts in git?

Tags: git

I am working with a remote git repository, I am the only one who commits into that repository, and only into the master -- that is, no branching, no merging.

Most of the time it works fine.

But sometimes, when I am trying to commit and push, I am getting some weird "fast forward rejected" message. Then, I am trying to synchronize by running git pull, I am getting my local copy into conflicted state :(

Last time it corrupted one of my binary files.

Any idea how that can happen that one user gets into conflicted state?

Comment: do you have multiple clones of that repository?

Comment: Well - in what way are the files different?  What does the log say?

Comment: @eis no -- I am working with one clone

Comment: I had the same problem on successive changes of the same lines of code, I guess this confuses the merge algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git fetch; gitk HEAD...@{u}` (or `git fetch; git log --graph --decorate --oneline HEAD...@{u}`) to see what is going on.

As long as your local branch and your upstream branch do not divert everything should be fine. If they do divert, check what kind of commit is responsible.

Also make sure that `git status --short` always shows a clean state. Having uncommitted changes hanging around might get you in similar trouble.

Comment: "As long as your local branch and your upstream branch do not divert everything should be fine" -- how that would be possible ?! I am the only one who is committing&pushing from one computer from same local directory.

Comment: @AdrianHerscu so did you do what was suggested? if so, could you add the output to the question?

Answer (score 1):

> that is, no branching, no merging

This is simply not true. You have branched, and you are merging. Here is how it happened:

1. You have at least two clones of your repository that you are actually working with.

   ```
   A --- B --- C <-- repo1:master
               ^
               |
          repo2:master
   ```

   Both repositories have a `master` branch, which usually point to the same commit.
2. You did some work in the one clone (commit `D`), pushing your changes to your central repository.

   ```
   A --- B --- C --- D <-- repo1:master
               ^
               |
          repo2:master
   ```
3. You did some other work (commit `E`) in the other clone *without pulling your first changes first*. At this point your history branched, whether you realize it or not. Yes, both branches are called `master`, but they live in different repositories, so they can diverge.

   ```
   A --- B --- C --- D <-- repo1:master
                \
                 \-- E <-- repo2:master
   ```
4. You tried to push `E` to a repository already containing `D` (with `master` pointing to that commit). This is the point where `git` realizes that your history has diverged, and consequently aborts the push operation.  This is because `git` sees that the `master` in the repository you are pushing to is not a parent of the `master` that you are trying to push. This is what is meant by `non-fast-forward rejected`.
5. You fetched `D` from the other repository, and started a merge, trying to create a merge commit `F` (`git pull` combines these two operations). Since `D` would be a parent of the new commit `F`, pushing `F` to `repo1` would succeed, but it has to be created first. Since your two branches have conflicting changes, `git` asks you to fix them.

   ```
   A --- B --- C --- D <-- repo1:master
                \     \
                 E --- F <-- repo2:master
   ```

As michas said, `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` is a good way to understand the status of your repository. Use this command frequently. I would strongly recommend to make an alias for it.

Comment: You are assuming that I did something crazy. I just did git clone into *one* location, changed some file(s), commited&pushed, then after several repetitions I am getting the "fast forward rejected" error message.