# git conflict during merge after cherry-picks for single user

Tags: git

I have a git branch `272_hppn_query_using_ms4` which is a branched from `270_ms4_migration_v2`. Below is the sequence of activities I did

- Fix something in `270_ms4_migration_v2` (change 1 or 2 files) (change #1)
- Fix another thin in `270_ms4_migration_v2` (change 1 or 2 files) (change #2)
- Go to branch `272_hppn_query_using_ms4`
- cherry-pick change #1
- cherry-pick change #2
- Go to `270_ms4_migration_v2`, made some complicated changes
- Go to `272_hppn_query_using_ms4`, and run the following

  ```
   git merge --no-commit --verbose  270_ms4_migration_v2
  ```

Got the following error messages:

> Auto-merging src/ms4Client/Ms4Client.java
>
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/ms4Client/Ms4Client.java
>
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

I'm quite surprised as I'm the only person working on this branch.

I did a `git status` before the merge and it says nothing to commit, working tree clean

Running `git log Ms4Client.java` on `272_hppn_query_using_ms4` gives me:

```
 commit b3d3fe72043270a5faf20f98f004b8d77cade5d2 (HEAD -> 272_hppn_query_using_ms4, 
 origin/272_hppn_query_using_ms4)
 Author: nobody@nobody.com
 Date:   Mon Dec 16 13:51:18 2019 +0800

        Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo()

        Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo(). Minor alignment fix

        (cherry picked from commit 0ec6bfefa33e85b4003f6ea32abb940db6e8a484)

 commit 9b94a860a92451f900187b20c23c080d181eb2ac
 Author: nobody@nobody.com
 Date:   Mon Dec 16 10:45:05 2019 +0800

        Add skeloton outline of getHppnInfoByGUID()

        (cherry picked from commit 8b640ca0dfe4613a1b0b67dda6c4a6d0131bbd7e)

commit dd89eb07436c14c94b04a7a2ebd6216b81f140ba
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Fri Dec 13 18:35:17 2019 +0800

         Initial commit
```

Doing `git log Ms4Client.java` on `270_ms4_migration_v2` returns:

```
commit 3fc75e94a3e2728f62ed51d06f7c58c604a17eb6 (HEAD -> refs/heads/270_ms4_migration_v2, refs/remotes/origin/270_ms4_migration_v2)
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Mon Dec 16 16:48:12 2019 +0800

    Fix import

commit 02956b00c445ed8d9124e4566c5ddf936cf0df8c
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Mon Dec 16 16:00:11 2019 +0800

    Throw Ms4WebServiceException when part not found in MS4

commit 0ec6bfefa33e85b4003f6ea32abb940db6e8a484
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Mon Dec 16 13:51:18 2019 +0800

    Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo()

    Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo(). Minor alignment fix

commit 8b640ca0dfe4613a1b0b67dda6c4a6d0131bbd7e
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Mon Dec 16 10:45:05 2019 +0800

    Add skeloton outline of getHppnInfoByGUID()

commit dd89eb07436c14c94b04a7a2ebd6216b81f140ba
Author: nobody@nobody.com
Date:   Fri Dec 13 18:35:17 2019 +0800

    Initial commit
```

Running `git log --oneline --decorate --graph -all --first-parent Ms4Client.java` returns:

```
* 3fc75e94a (origin/270_ms4_migration_v2, 270_ms4_migration_v2) Fix import
* 02956b00c Throw Ms4WebServiceException when part not found in MS4
* 0ec6bfefa Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo()
* 8b640ca0d Add skeloton outline of getHppnInfoByGUID()
| * b3d3fe720 (HEAD -> 272_hppn_query_using_ms4, origin/272_hppn_query_using_ms4) Rename Ms4Client.querySingleHppn() to Ms4Client.getHppnInfo()
| * 9b94a860a Add skeloton outline of getHppnInfoByGUID()
|/
* dd89eb074 Initial commit
* 8870529e0 (origin/270_ms4_migration, 270_ms4_migration) Fix the way we read the property file and change the property file name
* 42b0b9a46 Remove unneccessary initializers
* 0afea0149 Add/Update javadoc comments
* fc007813f Styling fix
* c781f8443 Styling fix
* 1f95f5c73 Remove useless comments
* bbd260165 Make setupMdgWebServiceConnection() throw exception during error and minor code structure fix
* 25c304848 Initial commit
```

Seems to me the changes are linear and straigforward, so I'm very confused why merge is throwing a conflict.

I've looked at [how it can be that a single user causes conflicts in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331777/how-it-can-be-that-a-single-user-causes-conflicts-in-git) and [Git cherry-pick will case merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897490/git-cherry-pick-will-case-merge-conflict) but seems to be not much of a help in here.

Comment: So have a look at the conflicting file and see what the conflict is. PS - that's not how you spell "skeleton".

Comment: Keep in mind that when you cherry-pick one (or more) commit from another branch, you are replaying them on top of a different base, and therefore you can get conflicts.  I don't see much here to get overly worried about.  Resolve the conflict, and move on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right when you said "Just resolve it", except I won't know the cause of the conflict. There shouldn't be any conflict as I didn't do any thing on Branch B (which is derived from Branch A) except cherry-pick some commits.

Comment: Without your actual files and/or commits, all we can say here is: *yes, this does happen* and show you some general cases where conflicts happen. Your *specific* case requires *your specific repository*, which we don't have.

Answer (score 1):

In the git merge process, a conflict means that both branches (the current branch, and the one being merged in) modified the same "hunk" of code ("hunk" being the term the git docs use, though I find it a bit annoying).  That roughly means they modified the same lines (or corresponding lines) in the same file.

When you cherry-pick, both branches definitely changed the same pieces of the code because you're duplicating the patch caused by the cherry-picked commit.  Now, git does try to recognize when both sides make *the same* change and not force manual conflict resolution, but if either branch contains further changes to the same hunk of code, then merge (which only looks at the start and end states, and not each commit in between) won't be able to tell that the same change was applied to both sides.  All it sees is a conflict in that case.

In any event, if the hangup is "why", I think examining the conflict in the code will likely help clarify that.

Now that said, in this case it's really unclear why you did the cherry-pick to begin with.

For one thing, here you are merging the entire branch back - which of course will include the two cherry-picked commits.  I'd understand that maybe the parent branch needed those 2 commits before the whole branch was ready, but then I usually would've expected other changes on the parent branch (changes that depend on the cherry picks).  Still I suppose maybe if the cherry picks had been pushed on the parent branch that might be the reason, except...

Even then, at the moment you did the cherry pick, the commits you wanted were the only commits on the branch; so why not just merge (possibly even by fast-forward) the changes back to the other branch?

All of which hints at an alternative solution, if you really don't want to resolve the conflict for whatever reason.  Assuming the parent branch hasn't been pushed to a remote, you could either (1) reset it to before the cherry-picks and then do the merge cleanly, or (2) just reset it to the same commit as the child branch.

Comment: At some point, I realized the I did the wrong thing. I should have just merged instead  instead of doing cherry-picks. I examined the source of conflict. git thought that changes I made after changes #2 have conflicts with the 2 cherry-picks.